# php submit form, data is not captured

Tags: php

I have got this code from a php lesson it worked on the lesson but not on my side, it basically transfer data from one page to another. 
can you spot what issue please with the variable, size? 
 everything else work 
Thanks

```
<form action= "form_script.php" method="POST">
  <p> Name : <input type ="text" name = "name" /></p>
  <p> Email : <input type ="text" name = "email" /></p

  <p>size: 
    <select name="size">
      <option value "small">small</option>
      <option value "medium">medium</option>
      <option value "large">large</option>
    </select>
  </p>

  <p>Gender :
    <input type = "radio" name ="gender" value ="Male"/> Male
    <input type = "radio" name ="gender" value ="Female"/> Female
  </p>

  <input type ="submit" name = "submit" value="submit Button"/>
</form>
```

on form_script.php

```
<?php
  $name =$_POST['name'];
  $email =$_POST['email'];
  $size =$_POST['size'];
  $gender =$_POST['gender'];

  print "<p>Name: $name </br> Email: $email </br>
  Size: $size </br>Gender: $gender </p>";
?>
```

Comment: missing 3 equal signs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With every HTML-attribute (e.g. `value`) you have to use `=` sign to specify the value:

```
<p>size: 
    <select name="size">
         <option value="small">small</option>
         <option value="medium">medium</option>
         <option value="large">large</option>
    </select>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the option tags to this :
`<option value="small"> small </option>`

You forgot the `=` sign

Answer (score 0):

try to format HTML correctly:

```
<form action="form_script.php" method="POST">
    <p> Name : <input type="text" name="name"/></p>
    <p> Email : <input type="text" name="email"/></p
    <p>size:
        <select name="size">
            <option value="small">small</option>
            <option value="medium">medium</option>
            <option value="large">large</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>Gender :
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male"/> Male
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female"/> Female
    </p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit Button"/>
</form>
```